# How to add the following to the loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using the following loop for some time now. Can you please advise how can I add one line to it, so every time I run it it runs and works for every new calculation?

```
Sub CVaR_R()
Const NUM_TIMES As Long = 1321
Dim ShtCalc As Worksheet, shtData As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, i As Long
Dim Arr As Variant

Set ShtCalc = Sheets("CVaR")
Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
Set rngCopy = shtData.Range("A1:A375")

   For i = 1 To NUM_TIMES
   Set rngCopy = shtData.Range(shtData.Cells(1, i), shtData.Cells(375, i))
With ShtCalc
   .Range("L5").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value

.Calculate

.Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("G10").Value
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

I need to add the following line to the code above, so every loop it changes the value.

```
.Range("G10").Formula = "=(1/G5)*SUM(L5:L" & .Cells(3, 7).Value & ")"
```

Thanks
West

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it already.

```
Sub CVaR_R()
Const NUM_TIMES As Long = 1321
Dim ShtCalc As Worksheet, shtData As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range, i As Long
Dim Arr As Variant

Set ShtCalc = Sheets("CVaR")
Set shtData = Sheets("Data")
Set rngCopy = shtData.Range("A1:A375")

   For i = 1 To NUM_TIMES
   Set rngCopy = shtData.Range(shtData.Cells(1, i), shtData.Cells(375, i))
With ShtCalc
   .Range("L5").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value
.Range("G10").Formula = "=(1/G5)*SUM(L5:L" & .Cells(3, 7).Value & ")"
.Calculate

.Range("I" & Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = .Range("G10").Value
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem was also the formula (I have not noticed that initially) in `.Cells(3, 7).Value`

Thanks
West